How to create CNN-LSTM architecture?
I try to create hybrid CNN and LSTM model. I had issue related to the shape of the architecture. This lead to the epoch could not run through the data 200 times.
My datasize is (96,2)
ERROR:
Epoch 1/200
    178/Unknown 9s 34ms/step - loss: 1.2366 - mse: 5.4560
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[40], line 4
      2 is_train = True
      3 if is_train:
----> 4    model_create.fit(train_dataset, epochs=200 , batch_size=128)

Cannot add tensor to the batch: number of elements does not match. Shapes are: [tensor]: [78,2], [batch]: [96,2]
     [[{{node IteratorGetNext}}]] [Op:__inference_one_step_on_iterator_23678]

CNN-LSTM model :
def create_model_architecture():
    model_cnn = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=64,
                               kernel_size=3,
                               activation='relu',
                               input_shape=input_data_shape),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2,strides=1, padding="same"),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=64,
                               kernel_size=3,
                               activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2,strides=1, padding="same"),    
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
        tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, return_sequences=True),
        tf.keras.layers.LSTM(16),
        tf.keras.layers.Reshape((-1,16)),
        #tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
    ])
    return model_cnn


Compile model
def create_model():
    tf.random.set_seed(51)

    model_create = create_model_architecture()
    #model_create = create_LSTM_model()
    model_create.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.Huber(),
                  optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
                  metrics=["mse"])
    return model_create

model_create = create_model()

model_create.summary()

model_create.fit(train_dataset, epochs=200 , batch_size=128)


I had try to add reshape before the flatten () function to change the shape. I also decrease the batch size and epoch size. None of this work. How could fit my model with train_data?

Can you try setting train_dataset.batch(1) and see if you're still getting errors? The errors you're observing are most likely because your training dataset has different dimensions (can consider padding your dataset to avoid this)

Also, note that the output dimension of tf.keras.layers.LSTM(16) is already (batch_size, 16)  - which I believe is what you desired. So tf.keras.layers.Reshape((-1,16)) seems unnecessary.

when you said padding dataset , it that mean the padding to the convolution section ?

Oh, I mean pad the input (only required if you're batching your inputs - especially during training). Can check this out https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data#batching_tensors_with_padding

Please try model_create.fit(train_dataset, epochs=200 , batch_size=1) and see if you're observing the same error.

Thank you for your support. I had try the batch size =1 . It seems to be the batch size =1 work. I will check out the padding and try use it to fix the problem

Cannot add tensor to the batch: number of elements does not match. Shapes are: [tensor]: [78,2], [batch]: [96,2]
The reason for this error is not related to your model architecture, but rather due to your data pipeline as the elements of your input data do not all have the exact same shape (this is required if you're batching your dataset - when you're using .fit(train_dataset, epochs=200 , batch_size=128), or calling train_dataset.batch(N) explicitly).
Possible Solution

Consider padding your data -
see https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data#batching_tensors_with_padding
Resize your data (if it make sense for your usecase - e.g: image data)
Use batch size of 1 (not recommended, because this would mean your SGD algorithm would have very high variance + training will be very slow as it doesn't fully utilise parallelization)

